# how to get notified through SNS when a user in AWS creates security group with ingress 0.0.0/0

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-security-group

When a user creates a security group with any ingress rule with 0.0.0.0/0 we should get notification. You need to listen to the event through the CloudWatch event or we need to run this lambda every 30 minutes and check all security groups with wideopen rules.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-security-group-changes-ec2/

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question to make clear what you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to achieve this:

1. Use AWS Config to monitor changes to a security group’s configuration.
2. Use AWS CloudTrail and Amazon CloudWatch Events to identify AWS API calls that could change the configurations of VPC security groups.

The following link explains how to automate Security Groups change detection using these two method and lambda, See [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-monitor-aws-account-configuration-changes-and-api-calls-to-amazon-ec2-security-groups/)